Docker setup for Django Rest Framework with gunicorn, mariadb and nginx - Error: Static files are not being served
I've been working on a project and now it's time to make it production ready. But I'm facing problems with my docker setup. I tried setting up the docker environment using mariaDB, gunicorn and nginx. The API works fine but the static files are not being served. I need help with this thing.
I also ran the command: python manage.py collectstatic in the docker container shell but no luck!
Here's my Dockerfile for the project
# Dockerfile

# Base image
FROM python:3.10

# Install dependencies
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy project files
COPY . /app

# Copy the wait-for-it.sh script
COPY ./wait-for-it.sh /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh

# Install Gunicorn
RUN pip install gunicorn

# Create static directory if it does not exist
RUN mkdir -p /app/static

# Collect static files
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

# Command to start Gunicorn
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "mental_health.wsgi:application"]


docker-compose.yml file
# docker-compose.yml

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb_container
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
      MYSQL_USER: mydatabaseuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypassword
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  django_app:
    build: .
    container_name: django_app
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=mysql://mydatabaseuser:mypassword@db/mydatabase
    volumes:
      - ./static:/app/static
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx_container
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./static:/app/static
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - django_app


default.conf (configuration file for nginx)
# default.conf

upstream mental_health {
    server django_app:8000;
}


server {
    listen 80;

    # Django app
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django_app:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # Serve static files
    location /static/ {
        alias /app/staticfiles/;
    }

    # Serve media files
    location /media/ {
        alias /app/media/;
    }

    client_max_body_size 10M;
}


settings.py
# settings.py

import logging
import os
from pathlib import Path

import firebase_admin
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from firebase_admin import credentials

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Load environment variables from .env.dev file
load_dotenv()

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'my-secret-key'

# DEBUG setting
DEBUG = os.getenv('DEBUG', False) == 'True'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get('ALLOWED_HOSTS').split(' ')

cred = credentials.Certificate(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "mental-heath-app-firebase-adminsdk-1dozp-8d8324a052.json"))
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'healthapp',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'mental_health.exception.custom_exception_handler',
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'mental_health.authentication.FirebaseAuthentication',
    ],
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'healthapp.middlewares.LogIPMiddleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mental_health.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mental_health.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE'),
        'USER': os.getenv('MYSQL_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    STATIC_DIR,
]

if not DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'healthapp.HealthAppUser'


# LOGGING
class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        if not hasattr(record, 'ip'):
            record.ip = 'N/A'

        if not hasattr(record, 'asctime'):
            record.asctime = self.formatTime(record, self.datefmt)

        formatted_log = f'{record.asctime} | {record.levelname} | {record.getMessage()}'
        return formatted_log

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'detailed': {
            '()': CustomFormatter,
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs', 'logs.log'),
            'formatter': 'detailed',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'detailed',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.server': {
            'handlers': [],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        '__main__': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}

if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs')):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs'))

Docker file for nginx
# Dockerfile (for nginx)

FROM nginx:latest

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf


middlewares.py file
import logging
import time

from django.db import connection

logger = logging.getLogger('__main__')

class LogIPMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        start_time = time.time()
        response = self.get_response(request)
        duration = time.time() - start_time
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', 'N/A')
        method = request.method
        path = request.path
        query_params = request.GET.urlencode()
        full_path = f'{path}?{query_params}' if query_params else path
        queries = len(connection.queries)
        status_code = response.status_code
        response_size = len(response.content)
        user_authenticated = request.user.is_authenticated

        logger.info(
            f'IP: {ip} | Method: {method} | Path: {full_path} | Duration: {duration:.2f}s | Queries: {queries} | Status Code: {status_code} | Response Size: {response_size} bytes | Authenticated: {user_authenticated}',
            extra={'ip': ip}
        )
        return response


Below is my folder structure for this project:
# folder structure

healthapp/
│
├── __pycache__/
├── migrations/
│   └── __init__.py
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── middlewares.py
├── models.py
├── serializers.py
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
├── utils.py
├── views.py
│
├── media/
│
├── mental_health/
│   ├── __pycache__/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── authentication.py
│   ├── exception.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── uris.py
│   └── wsgi.py
│
├── nginx/
│   ├── default.conf
│   └── Dockerfile
│
├── static/
├── staticfiles/
│
├── .env
├── .gitignore
├── backup.json
├── commands.txt
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── manage.py
├── mental-health-app-firebase-adminsdk.json
├── requirements.txt
├── stop_dockers.sh
└── wait-for-it.sh


The API is working properly, so is the database but when I visit the django administration panel it doesn't load the css files. Only shows the HTML structure. And in the terminal it prints the below message:
django_app         | Internal Server Error: /static/admin/css/responsive.css
django_app         | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_app         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
django_app         |     response = get_response(request)
django_app         |   File "/app/healthapp/middlewares.py", line 23, in __call__
django_app         |     response_size = len(response.content)
django_app         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 407, in content
django_app         |     raise AttributeError(
django_app         | AttributeError: This FileResponse instance has no `content` attribute. Use `streaming_content` instead.
django_app         | Internal Server Error: /static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js
django_app         | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_app         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
django_app         |     response = get_response(request)
django_app         |   File "/app/healthapp/middlewares.py", line 23, in __call__
django_app         |     response_size = len(response.content)
django_app         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 407, in content
django_app         |     raise AttributeError(
django_app         | AttributeError: This FileResponse instance has no `content` attribute. Use `streaming_content` instead.

I tried to run my django rest framework project in a production ready docker environment. The API and the database seems to work fine but the static files are not being served even after installing nginx.
I also ran the command: python manage.py collectstatic in the docker container shell but no luck!
I want the static files to be served properly.

The volumes: blocks in the Compose file are hiding the /app/static directories in both containers, and replacing the image contents with the contents of the host's ./static directory.  Nothing you show copies files into that directory.  Volumes tend to not be reliable ways to try to share fixed content between containers.  Can you use Django's static file server, or COPY the static assets into a custom Nginx image?

Unrelated to your problem, alternate to the wait-for-it.sh script - use the docker compose healthcheck depdendency like healthcheck.sh.
